# Searching for a filename on a Mac

Tags: macos, finder

I find it very frustrating that when I use Finder or Search on my Mac  I cannot locate a file - all I get is the word if it internally occurs. Example: currently searching for my edit of Shakespeare's THE TEMPEST, I get only contacts, MACBETH and other files which include the word Tempest within the file! I know that this text is in my computer on the hard drive by the by.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a question. Also include your macOS version just in case.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/searching-by-file-name-as-opposed-to-name-and-contents-in-lion#18486), one of SE's other sites. From the top and accepted answer:

1. Open a finder window
2. Open the folder you wish to search in
3. Click in the search box
4. Type the text you want to find
5. A dropdown should appear like the one in the image below which
   allows you to select the 'Filename contains' option

Alternatively, you can also search for `name:<filename>`, which will bring up files with `<filename>` in their, uh, *filename*.

For screenshots and more details, check out [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18486) answer.